# How can I stop exporting SQL Query result to CSV if the CSV is empty in Java

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, csv

I have a Java Script which is running a SQL Query and pushing the output in a CSV File. Another JAR I have created which is taking the output file and triggering an email.

Everything is sorted so far but I need assistance on if the SQL Query return empty data one day as I am planning to run the JAR file everyday to pickup everyday discrepancy data then it should not export any CSV file and thereby unnecessary email won't trigger.

Here is my script:

```
enter code here    
    
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
        System.out.println("Connection established");
          //Creating the Statement
          Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
          //Query to retrieve records
          String query = "SELECT * FROM usr WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (usr_udf_costcenter, '^[a-zA-Z]*$') and USR_LOGIN not like '%DELETED%' and USR_display_name not like '%DELETED%' and USR_LOGIN not like '%TEST%'";
          //Executing the query
          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
          //Instantiating the CSVWriter class
          //Writer fileWriter = new FileWriter("c:\\data\\output.txt", false); //overwrites file
          
          String filepath = "/app/abvidmdv/temp/suvradip/";
          String filename = filepath + "Invalid_Costcenters" + new SimpleDateFormat("(d-MMMM-yyyy)").format(new Date()) + ".csv";
          CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(filename, false));
          ResultSetMetaData Mdata = rs.getMetaData();
          Mdata.getColumnName(1);
          //Writing data to a csv file
          String line1[] = {Mdata.getColumnName(20), Mdata.getColumnName(6), Mdata.getColumnName(132), Mdata.getColumnName(129), Mdata.getColumnName(99)};
          writer.writeNext(line1);
          String data[] = new String[5];
          while(rs.next()) {
         
              data[0] = rs.getString("usr_login");
              data[1] = rs.getString("usr_display_name");
              data[2] = rs.getString("usr_udf_costcenter");
              data[3] = rs.getString("usr_udf_costcentername");
              data[4] = rs.getString("usr_create");
             writer.writeNext(data);
          }
          //Flushing data from writer to file
          writer.flush();
          System.out.println("Data entered");
    } catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally
    {
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
      
}
```

}

This script exports the data to the CSV. I believe I need to add some condition in this class itself as in the email triggering class there is not point of placing any filter. Please assist and let me know where I need to add what condition if the content of the SQL is empty for that day.

Comment: Personally, I would suggest `SELECT COUNT(*)` and check for "0".

Answer (score 1):

Back in the early 2000s, we would run 2 different SQL queries to determine if we need to export data, and then only export when there is data available.

You could run a query before this to count the number of records that meet your export criteria, and then continue with the export if the record count is > 0.

For example:

```
SQL 1: "SELECT count(*) FROM usr WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (usr_udf_costcenter, '^[a-zA-Z]*$') and USR_LOGIN not like '%DELETED%' and USR_display_name not like '%DELETED%' and USR_LOGIN not like '%TEST%'";
```

If this returns more than 0 records, then execute the code you have above

Comment: That is definitely an option but I wanted to place a if else statement in this script as if I place another SQL statement to check then again I need to place condition in the email script too. Can you please assist me placing a condition in this script which will stop exporting if the file is empty

Comment: Write a method to count the number of records you would export. call this countRecords() and have it return an integer. Then, if (countRecords() > 0) { do the export}